# Why I get error converting date to format?

Tags: php, laravel

I have code in Laravel, that converts date from db to specific format:

```
if (!empty($timestamp)){

            $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

            $tz = new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Baku');

            $date->setTimezone($tz);

            return $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
```

It works perfect till I change format to:

```
return $date->format("Y-m-d H:i");
```

Without seconds.

Error is:

```
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\Dev\ch-guestsreg-backend\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php"
line: 917
message: "Data missing"
```

Full code is, it gets data from DB and mapping it:

```
 public function collection()
    {

        if (count($this->id)) {
            $visitors = Visitor::select(
                'idVisitor', 
                'firstname', 
                'lastname', 
                'middlename',
                'birthday',             
                'document_number', 
                'pincode', 
                'company', 
                'idEvent',
                'code',
                'visitors.created_at',
                'users.name',
                'visitors.date_cheked',
                'visitors.status'
            )->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'visitors.user_cheked')
            ->whereIn("idVisitor", $this->id)->get();


            foreach($visitors as $v) {  
                $dt1 = $v->date_cheked; // here I copy values
                $dt2 = $v->created_at;

                $v->date_cheked = null; // Reset 
                $v->created_at = null;
                $v->birthday = !empty($v->birthday) ?  Carbon::parse($v->birthday)->format('d/m/Y') : null;

                $v->ckecked = $v->ckecked == 0 ? Lang::get('excel.no') : Lang::get('excel.yes');
                $v->idVisitor = self::$i++;
                $v->date_cheked = $this->toLocalTime($dt1);
                $v->created_at = $this->toLocalTime($dt2);
                $v->status = $this->getStatus($v);
            }

            return $visitors;
        }
        return Visitor::all();
    }
}
```

So, perhaps problem in assigning new date to `$v->created_at`. Because Laravel thinks that `$v->created_at`  is Carbon type.

Comment: All field are timestamp type in format `2019-08-22 13:08:59`

Comment: And I tried convert this UTC time to local timezone

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this code? I tested this code and it works fine. Also, as you can see, the exception is throwing from `Carbon`, which you haven't used in this piece of code. so probably the error is in somewhere else.

Comment: I think the error is happening after the `return`

Comment: Yes, it is right, but why? See my code

Comment: There is no error in your code. See, another one has posted an answer saying there is no error. The error is in somewhere else in your project.

Comment: I have posted full code and my assumptions

Comment: I tried your code, and it works! could you give more error info?